# Copy last non-blank cell in a coulmn to the last non-blank cell in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy the last non-empty cell in column C into the cell after the last entry in column A. For example:

```
 Row    Column A    ...    Column C
1        X                  Y
2        X                  Y
3        Y                  Y
4                           Y
5                           Y
```

As shown, the entries, X, in column A end on the 2nd row, whilst Y ends on the 5th row in Column C. I want this last entry to be copied into Column A

I have:

```
Sub RangeSel()
Dim ColA As Range
Dim ColC As Range


Set ColC = Cells("C" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
Set ColA = Cells("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

ColC.Copy (ColA)
End Sub
```

But keep getting errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-Liner:

```
Cells(Columns("A").End(xldown).row+1,"A")=Columns("C").End(xlDown)
```

A bit prettier and more readable:

```
Dim contentOfLastCellOfColC As String
contentOfLastCellOfColC = Columns("C").End(xlDown).Value

Dim lastCellOfColA As Range
Set lastCellOfColA = Columns("A").End(xlDown)

Cells(lastCellOfColA.Row + 1, "A") = contentOfLastCellOfColC
```

If this helped, please reward me with a green tick ;)

Comment: That's what I was looking for! How about if I want to change it up a bit and copy the row number of the last cell in column C to the last cell of Column A?

Comment: If you want take the row number of the last cell in "C" and overwrite the last cell of column A:


`   Dim rowNrOfLastCellOfColC As Integer
    rowNrOfLastCellOfColC = Columns("C").End(xlDown).Row
    
    Dim lastCellOfColA As Range
    Set lastCellOfColA = Columns("A").End(xlDown)
    
    Cells(lastCellOfColA.Row, "A") = rowNrOfLastCellOfColC`

Comment: Okay, can't figure out how to write a code into the comment section... anyhow, the one liner version to it: Cells(Columns("A").End(xldown).row,"A")=Columns("C").End(xlDown).Row